# How to deny the drop event?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

Before version 2016.3.914, it was possible to cancel a drop event by calling `e.setStatusClass("k-denied");`

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dragAndDrop: true,
  dataSource: [
    { text: "foo", items: [
      { text: "bar" }
    ] }
  ],
  drag: function(e) {
    e.setStatusClass("k-denied");
  }
});
```

However, starting from version 2016.3.914, the pre-defined status classe k-denied doesn't work anymore.  The [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#events-drag) says that `k-i-` should be added as class prefix but `k-i-denied` doesn't work as the cancel icon doesn't appear and the drop is still allowed.

Please note that from version 2016.3.914 the naming convention for pre-defined status classes is k-i-className.

> Note that status classes are returned without the k- prefix by
>   e.statusClass, but this prefix is required when setting a predefined
>   status class via e.setStatusClass. A prefix is not required if setting
>   a custom status CSS class.

Comment: What exactly is it you want to happen? Allow dragging but prevent dropping?

Comment: The provided code is just to simplify the problem.  No matter what your logic is,, you can't prevent a drop using the `.setStatusClass("k-denied");`.  When I posted the question, I already had the anwser.  Since this wasn't documented by kendo, I felt it could help someone else.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that I don't think `setStatusClass` is the way to go at all. I'm trying to understand what it is that you want to do to offer you a good solution.

Comment: The idea was to prevent a node from being drop on specific elements.  Calling the `setStatusClass("k-i-cancel")` on the drag event is the same as calling a `setValid(false)` in the drop event, except that the user will see the the cancel icon which ain't the case if you use `setValid` alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation was right about one thing.  We do have to use the `k-i-` prefix.  However, what the documentation doesn't tell you is the fact that kendo has changed the pre-defined status classes from `k-denied` to `k-i-cancel`

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dragAndDrop: true,
  dataSource: [
    { text: "foo", items: [
      { text: "bar" }
    ] }
  ],
  drag: function(e) {
    e.setStatusClass("k-i-cancel");
  }
});
```